# Why do I obtain black screen for both remote and local users in a video call using agora rtc?

Tags: flutter, agora.io

I have tried to follow the example of using agora with flutter and have included the permissions as recommended in the documentation. However, whenever I run the app on two emulator devices, I obtain black screens for remote and local users joining the channel.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:agora_rtc_engine/rtc_engine.dart';
import 'package:agora_rtc_engine/rtc_local_view.dart' as RtcLocalView;
import 'package:agora_rtc_engine/rtc_remote_view.dart' as RtcRemoteView;

const appId = "ba997ed994ca4163a06898c8fd9e7f1b";
const tempToken =
    "006ba997ed994ca4163a06898c8fd9e7f1bIAA4Dx064RTGa9iaVmXQjxtTuvgDsBgiMUiuWhMBW9zsH+LcsooAAAAAEADkBngOXNpIYQEAAQBb2khh";
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int? _remoteUid;
  late RtcEngine _engine;
  bool _localUserJoined = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    initAgora();
  }

  Future<void> initAgora() async {
    // retrieve permissions
    await [Permission.microphone, Permission.camera].request();

    //create the engine
    _engine = await RtcEngine.create(appId);
    await _engine.enableLocalVideo(true);
    await _engine.enableVideo();

    _engine.setEventHandler(
      RtcEngineEventHandler(
        error: (code) {
          setState(() {
            print('OnError: $code');
          });
        },
        joinChannelSuccess: (String channel, int uid, int elapsed) {
          print("local user $uid joined");
          setState(() {
            _localUserJoined = true;
          });
        },
        userJoined: (int uid, int elapsed) {
          print("remote user $uid joined");
          setState(() {
            _remoteUid = uid;
          });
        },
        userOffline: (int uid, UserOfflineReason reason) {
          print("remote user $uid left channel");
          setState(() {
            _remoteUid = null;
          });
        },
      ),
    );

    await _engine.joinChannel(tempToken, "test1", null, 0);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Agora Video Call'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Center(
                child: _remoteVideo(),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 150,
                  child: _localUserJoined
                      ? RtcLocalView.TextureView()
                      : const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // Display remote user's video
  Widget _remoteVideo() {
    if (_remoteUid != null) {
      return RtcRemoteView.SurfaceView(uid: _remoteUid!);
    } else {
      return const Text(
        'Please wait for remote user to join',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      );
    }
  }
}
```

This is what I obtain on the log console when running the app

```
D/EGL_emulation( 7173): eglMakeCurrent: 0xd7feda20: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe374ef80)
I/OpenGLRenderer( 7173): Davey! duration=779ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=685691964116, Vsync=685708630782, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=685708797700, AnimationStart=685708875900, PerformTraversalsStart=685708953100, DrawStart=685715178000, SyncQueued=685747716900, SyncStart=685790044600, IssueDrawCommandsStart=685795726600, SwapBuffers=686079910600, FrameCompleted=686513563000, DequeueBufferDuration=138518000, QueueBufferDuration=25800000, 
E/BluetoothAdapter( 7173): Bluetooth binder is null
D/agora-jni( 7173): android bridge create done...
E/libc    ( 7173): Access denied finding property "net.dns1"
E/libc    ( 7173): Access denied finding property "net.dns2"
E/libc    ( 7173): Access denied finding property "net.dns3"
E/libc    ( 7173): Access denied finding property "net.dns4"
E/libc    ( 7173): Access denied finding property "net.dns1"
E/libc    ( 7173): Access denied finding property "net.dns2"
E/libc    ( 7173): Access denied finding property "net.dns3"
E/libc    ( 7173): Access denied finding property "net.dns4"
W/deo_call_trial( 7173): Verification of java.lang.Iterable kotlin.collections.ArraysKt___ArraysKt.asIterable(long[]) took 101.748ms
I/deo_call_trial( 7173): Background young concurrent copying GC freed 22938(1311KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 47% free, 1429KB/2719KB, paused 3.944ms total 146.642ms
I/CameraManagerGlobal( 7173): Connecting to camera service
E/libc    ( 7173): Access denied finding property "net.dns1"
E/libc    ( 7173): Access denied finding property "net.dns2"
E/libc    ( 7173): Access denied finding property "net.dns3"
E/libc    ( 7173): Access denied finding property "net.dns4"
D/*WEBRTCN*( 7173): SetRenderAndroidVM
I/VideoCapabilities( 7173): Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
D/HostConnection( 7173): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xc43a4920, tid 7265
D/HostConnection( 7173): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
W/GDPGlUtil( 7173): unable to find RGB8888 / 3 EGLConfig
D/EGL_emulation( 7173): eglCreateContext: 0xe37c1140: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/GDPGlUtil( 7173): EGLContext created, client version 2
D/EGL_emulation( 7173): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe37c1140: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd80280d0)
I/GDPAndroid( 7173): cores:4
I/chatty  ( 7173): uid=10133(com.nawraaradi.video_call_trial1) GENP.0 identical 4 lines
I/GDPAndroid( 7173): cores:4
I/GDPAndroid( 7173): max freq:1991000
I/GDPAndroid( 7173): total mem:2089172992
V/MediaRouter( 7173): Selecting route: RouteInfo{ name=Phone, description=null, status=null, category=RouteCategory{ name=System types=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO  groupable=false }, supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO , presentationDisplay=null }
W/AudioTrack( 7173): Use of stream types is deprecated for operations other than volume control
W/AudioTrack( 7173): See the documentation of AudioTrack() for what to use instead with android.media.AudioAttributes to qualify your playback use case
V/MediaRouter( 7173): Selecting route: RouteInfo{ name=Phone, description=null, status=null, category=RouteCategory{ name=System types=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO  groupable=false }, supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO , presentationDisplay=null }
I/flutter ( 7173): local user 180939488 joined
I/flutter ( 7173): remote user 979896972 joined
I/deo_call_trial( 7173): Background concurrent copying GC freed 10893(1140KB) AllocSpace objects, 10(328KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 1873KB/3746KB, paused 1.984ms total 460.037ms
W/Gralloc3( 7173): allocator 3.x is not supported
D/AudioTrack( 7173): getTimestamp_l(9): device stall time corrected using current time 720119488800
W/System.err( 7173): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)
W/System.err( 7173):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:159)
W/System.err( 7173):    at io.agora.rtc.gdp.GDPAndroid.readOneLine(GDPAndroid.java:383)
W/System.err( 7173):    at io.agora.rtc.gdp.GDPAndroid.getCpuTemperature(GDPAndroid.java:362)
W/System.err( 7173): Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:252)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
W/System.err( 7173):    at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7255)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:482)
W/System.err( 7173):    ... 3 more
W/System.err( 7173): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)
W/System.err( 7173):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:159)
W/System.err( 7173):    at io.agora.rtc.gdp.GDPAndroid.readOneLine(GDPAndroid.java:383)
W/System.err( 7173):    at io.agora.rtc.gdp.GDPAndroid.getCpuTemperature(GDPAndroid.java:362)
W/System.err( 7173): Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:252)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
W/System.err( 7173):    at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7255)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:482)
W/System.err( 7173):    ... 3 more
W/GENP.0  ( 7173): type=1400 audit(0.0:50): avc: denied { read } for name="temp" dev="sysfs" ino=13214 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c133,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 app=com.nawraaradi.video_call_trial1
D/eglCodecCommon( 7173): allocate: Ask for block of size 0x71000
D/eglCodecCommon( 7173): allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3ff0fa000 size 0x72000
D/HostConnection( 7173): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xdb65ea40, tid 7287
D/HostConnection( 7173): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
D/EGL_emulation( 7173): eglCreateContext: 0xdb61bfe0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation( 7173): eglMakeCurrent: 0xd7feda20: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe374ef80)
E/libc    ( 7173): Access denied finding property "net.dns1"
E/libc    ( 7173): Access denied finding property "net.dns2"
E/libc    ( 7173): Access denied finding property "net.dns3"
E/libc    ( 7173): Access denied finding property "net.dns4"
W/GENP.0  ( 7173): type=1400 audit(0.0:52): avc: denied { read } for name="temp" dev="sysfs" ino=13214 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c133,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 app=com.nawraaradi.video_call_trial1
W/GENP.0  ( 7173): type=1400 audit(0.0:53): avc: denied { read } for name="temp" dev="sysfs" ino=13214 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c133,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 app=com.nawraaradi.video_call_trial1
W/System.err( 7173): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)
W/System.err( 7173):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:159)
W/System.err( 7173):    at io.agora.rtc.gdp.GDPAndroid.readOneLine(GDPAndroid.java:383)
W/System.err( 7173):    at io.agora.rtc.gdp.GDPAndroid.getCpuTemperature(GDPAndroid.java:362)
W/System.err( 7173): Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:252)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
W/System.err( 7173):    at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7255)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:482)
W/System.err( 7173):    ... 3 more
W/System.err( 7173): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)
W/System.err( 7173):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:159)
W/System.err( 7173):    at io.agora.rtc.gdp.GDPAndroid.readOneLine(GDPAndroid.java:383)
W/System.err( 7173):    at io.agora.rtc.gdp.GDPAndroid.getCpuTemperature(GDPAndroid.java:362)
W/System.err( 7173): Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:252)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
W/System.err( 7173):    at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7255)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:482)
W/System.err( 7173):    ... 3 more
D/EGL_emulation( 7173): eglMakeCurrent: 0xdb61bfe0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb45e3130)
E/EGL_emulation( 7173): eglQueryContext 32c0  EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
E/EGL_emulation( 7173): tid 7287: eglQueryContext(1903): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
I/AGORA_SDK( 7173): Surface changed to width 1440 height 2112
D/HostConnection( 7173): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb777c3d0, tid 7292
D/HostConnection( 7173): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
D/EGL_emulation( 7173): eglMakeCurrent: 0xd7feda20: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe374ef80)
I/deo_call_trial( 7173): Background young concurrent copying GC freed 11412(1055KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(104KB) LOS objects, 39% free, 2252KB/3746KB, paused 8.165ms total 477.502ms
D/EGL_emulation( 7173): eglCreateContext: 0xe37c26a0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
I/OpenGLRenderer( 7173): Davey! duration=1542ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=721175292876, Vsync=721525292862, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=721539986100, AnimationStart=721540060100, PerformTraversalsStart=721555098200, DrawStart=722464197900, SyncQueued=722467391200, SyncStart=722613505700, IssueDrawCommandsStart=722613690600, SwapBuffers=722639609400, FrameCompleted=722864107200, DequeueBufferDuration=2333000, QueueBufferDuration=1409000, 
I/Choreographer( 7173): Skipped 80 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/EGL_emulation( 7173): eglMakeCurrent: 0xd7feda20: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe374ef80)
D/EGL_emulation( 7173): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe37c26a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc4043740)
E/EGL_emulation( 7173): eglQueryContext 32c0  EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
E/EGL_emulation( 7173): tid 7292: eglQueryContext(1903): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
I/AGORA_SDK( 7173): Surface changed to width 350 height 525
D/AudioTrack( 7173): getTimestamp_l(9): device stall time corrected using current time 723307290400
D/EGL_emulation( 7173): eglMakeCurrent: 0xd7feda20: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe374ef80)
D/HostConnection( 7173): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaf53cf20, tid 7290
D/HostConnection( 7173): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
E/libc    ( 7173): Access denied finding property "net.dns1"
E/libc    ( 7173): Access denied finding property "net.dns2"
E/libc    ( 7173): Access denied finding property "net.dns3"
E/libc    ( 7173): Access denied finding property "net.dns4"
W/System.err( 7173): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)
W/System.err( 7173):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:159)
W/System.err( 7173):    at io.agora.rtc.gdp.GDPAndroid.readOneLine(GDPAndroid.java:383)
W/System.err( 7173):    at io.agora.rtc.gdp.GDPAndroid.getCpuTemperature(GDPAndroid.java:362)
W/System.err( 7173): Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:252)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
W/System.err( 7173):    at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7255)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:482)
W/System.err( 7173):    ... 3 more
W/System.err( 7173): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)
W/System.err( 7173):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:159)
W/System.err( 7173):    at io.agora.rtc.gdp.GDPAndroid.readOneLine(GDPAndroid.java:383)
W/System.err( 7173):    at io.agora.rtc.gdp.GDPAndroid.getCpuTemperature(GDPAndroid.java:362)
W/System.err( 7173): Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
W/GENP.0  ( 7173): type=1400 audit(0.0:54): avc: denied { read } for name="temp" dev="sysfs" ino=13214 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c133,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 app=com.nawraaradi.video_call_trial1
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:252)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
W/System.err( 7173):    at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7255)
W/System.err( 7173):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:482)
W/System.err( 7173):    ... 3 more
W/GENP.0  ( 7173): type=1400 audit(0.0:55): avc: denied { read } for name="temp" dev="sysfs" ino=13214 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c133,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 app=com.nawraaradi.video_call_trial1
D/HostConnection( 7173): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xdb660610, tid 7288
D/HostConnection( 7173): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
D/HostConnection( 7173): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xdb661f60, tid 7191
D/HostConnection( 7173): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2
```

I have even verified that the front camera for the emulators are connected to the webcam of my PC. Kindly, if anyone who had this problem before and have overcame it please recommend me a solution .

Comment: Make sure your temporary token is not expired .

Answer (score 1):

`allocator 3.x is not supported` this seems like an emulator error. You can try running it on a physical device or maybe try this for your emulator `flutter run --enable-software-rendering`